# Add a space in lambda function

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have 2 columns in my data frame - ASIN and keywords . I am trying to groupby ASINs , the groupby is working fine

```
    ASIN            keywords
0   B07GFGXMZZ  mangalagiri dress materials
1   B07GFGXMZZ  pure cotton dress materials for women
2   B07GFGXMZZ  suit material party wear for women
3   B076BL4CWB  dhakai jamdani
4   B076BL4CWB  jamdani
```

Groupby Code

```
df.groupby('ASIN').apply(lambda x: x.sum())
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD2NK.png)

but how to add a space for each lambda iteration as of now it is not doing , you can observe the same in output image i have linked

i Tried

```
df.groupby('ASIN').apply(lambda x:" ".join(x.sum()))
```

But it didn't work

```
ASIN
9801321261    98013212619801321261 cane mat with runnercane ...
B008YLNICE    B008YLNICEB008YLNICEB008YLNICEB008YLNICEB008YL...
B00P81OJ26    B00P81OJ26B00P81OJ26B00P81OJ26B00P81OJ26B00P81...
B010SZBHEE    B010SZBHEEB010SZBHEEB010SZBHEEB010SZBHEEB010SZ...
B01143KAY2    B01143KAY2B01143KAY2B01143KAY2B01143KAY2B01143...
B0157XMD4A                      B0157XMD4A elephant painted box
B0157XMRJ6    B0157XMRJ6B0157XMRJ6B0157XMRJ6B0157XMRJ6B0157X...
```

Comment: Is not completely clear what is your goal, since the first dataframe you posted does not contains the entries shown in your expected output.

Comment: I used Power BI to Groupby , it was a matter of few clicks . Thanks for the response . When i was using groupby ealier - i wasn't able to add a space between 2 strings